# Why I cannot catch my exception?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, exception

I'm developing a web-app using SpringBoot. Everything is going well, but I have a little problem:

**I cannot catch an exception.** A custom one:

```
public class BadCredentialsException extends RuntimeException {
    public BadCredentialsException(String message){
        super(message);
    }
}
```

**I want to catch it in a OncePerRequestFilter, this one:**

```
@Slf4j
public class AuthExceptionHandlerFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        log.debug("AuthExceptionFilter");
        try {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (BadRequestAuthException e) {
            log.info("Bad auth request received: {}", e.getMessage());
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, e.getMessage());

        //===========HERE==========
        } catch (BadCredentialsException ex) {
            log.info("Bad credentials: {}", ex.getMessage());
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I have an AuthFilter too, but it's unrelated. **And a DefaultExceptionHandler, what catches everything:**

```
@Slf4j
public class DefaultExceptionHandlerFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try{
            log.debug("DefaultExceptionHandler");
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }catch(RuntimeException e){
            log.warn("Internal server error: {}", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }catch (Exception e){
            log.error("Unknown exception: {}", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

**All the filters are configured by this:**

```
@Configuration
public class FilterConfig {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<DefaultExceptionHandlerFilter> exceptionHandlerFilterBean(){
        FilterRegistrationBean<DefaultExceptionHandlerFilter> filter = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        filter.setFilter(defaultExceptionFilter());
        filter.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultExceptionHandlerFilter defaultExceptionFilter(){
        return new DefaultExceptionHandlerFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<AuthExceptionHandlerFilter> authExceptionHandlerFilterFilterBean(){
        FilterRegistrationBean<AuthExceptionHandlerFilter> filter = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        filter.setFilter(authExceptionHandlerFilter());
        filter.setOrder(1);
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthExceptionHandlerFilter authExceptionHandlerFilter(){
        return new AuthExceptionHandlerFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<AuthFilter> authFilterBean (AccessTokenService authService){
        FilterRegistrationBean<AuthFilter> authFilter = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        authFilter.setFilter(loginFilter(authService));
        authFilter.setOrder(2);
        return authFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthFilter loginFilter(AccessTokenService authService){
        return new AuthFilter(authService);
    }
}
```

**The following method throws the exception:** (Called by a service, what is called by the @RestController)

```
private SkyXpUser getAuthenticatedUser(LoginRequest loginRequest){
    SkyXpUser user = userService.getUserByName(loginRequest.getUserName());
    if(user == null){
        throw new BadCredentialsException("User cannot be found. Username: " + loginRequest.getUserName());
    }

    if(!user.getPassword().equals(loginRequest.getPassword())){
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Password is incorrect.");
    }
    return user;
}
```

**And i get the following stack trace**, when I enter an username what does not exists, or wrong email:

```
2018-05-29 19:23:16.841 ERROR 8924 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.filter.DefaultExceptionHandlerFilter   : Unknown exception: Request processing failed; nested exception is skyxplore.auth.domain.exception.BadCredentialsException: User cannot be found. Username: asad
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is skyxplore.auth.domain.exception.BadCredentialsException: User cannot be found. Username: asad
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

    at skyxplore.filter.AuthFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthFilter.java:51)

    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

    at skyxplore.filter.AuthExceptionHandlerFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthExceptionHandlerFilter.java:22)

    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

    at skyxplore.filter.DefaultExceptionHandlerFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultExceptionHandlerFilter.java:19)

    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: skyxplore.auth.domain.exception.BadCredentialsException: User cannot be found. Username: asad
    at skyxplore.auth.service.AccessTokenService.getAuthenticatedUser(AccessTokenService.java:46)
    at skyxplore.auth.service.AccessTokenService.login(AccessTokenService.java:31)
    at skyxplore.auth.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:26)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
    ... 53 more
```

The stack trace says **All the 3 filters were called**, and the **DefaultExceptionHandler's "Exception" catch part catched the exception, not the "RuntimeException" one.**

**While the AuthFilter's "BadCredentialsException" part should catch this exception, once it is a BadCredentialsException.** Or the DefaultExceptionHandler's "RuntimeException" part, because BadCredentialsException extends RuntimeException.

**What the hack is happening here? How can I solve?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand it right, you try to handle a exception from a controller. You need something that handle the exception from your controller.

GlobalHandler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler {



@ExceptionHandler(value = BadCredentialsException.class)
public ResponseEntity handleAllExceptions(BadCredentialsException ex){
    //DO Something
    return new ResponseEntity("Error", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
}
```

There are different ways see:
https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc
or [What are the advantages of @ControllerAdvice over @ExceptionHandler or HandlerExceptionResolver for handling exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35323174/what-are-the-advantages-of-controlleradvice-over-exceptionhandler-or-handlerex/35371960)

Comment: Well, It's good for a solution, but I still not understand, why mine one does not work :D Thank you, I'll use these advices.

Comment: the problem is that your exception is wrapped in a NestedServletException thats why the "exception" part gets the exception ... its not an Runtimeexception and not your own type of exception ... after wrapping its an NestedServletException https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/NestedServletException.html

Comment: Second line, in the stack trace... Why I had not read about it before?